# Modify the text of table cells using js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in html and I want to alter the text inside different cells using js. My table looks like this:

```
    <tr><td colspan="7" style="text-align:center;">Calendar evenimente tds</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Data1</th>
      <th>Data2</th>
      <th>Data3</th>
      <th>Data4</th>
      <th>Data5</th>
      <th>Data6</th>
      <th>Data7</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="col1row1">null</td>
      <td id="col2row1">null</td>
      <td id="col3row1">null</td>
      <td id="col4row1">null</td>
      <td id="col5row1">null</td>
      <td id="col6row1">null</td>
      <td id="col7row1">null</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my js script looks like this:

```
var j=0;
for(j=0;j<=7;j++)
document.getElementById("col"+j+"row1").innerHTML=j;
```

but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

My question is whats the propper way of modifying the text inside a HTML table cell and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your initial value of `j` is `0`. Then you select an element with `document.getElementById("col0row1")`, which isn't there. So the `getElementById` returns `null` instead of an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first iteration of your loop fails because there is no `col0`. Rather than iterate over IDs like this, you can simply loop over the elements by tag:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('td')).forEach((td, index) => {
  td.innerHTML = index
})
```

If you want the count to start at 1, use `td.innerHTML = index + 1` instead.

Comment: thanks for the idea , but it is just a test code, later I would like to easily pick every row or column individualy

Answer (score 1):

loop are calling an ID that does not exist.make for loop starts with 1 instead of zero as there is no col0row1 in your html

```
 var j;
for(j=1;j<=7;j++){
document.getElementById("col"+j+"row1").innerHTML=j;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As at j = 0 there is no element with id "col0row1" hence the uncaught error.

```html
var j = 1
for(j=1;j<=7;j++){
    document.getElementById("col" + j + "row1").innerHTML = j;
}
```

Comment: it should be `...= j`, not `...= "j"`